# Memory leak with Perl's LWP using HTTPS

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, lwp

I think I found a memory leak with LWP when connecting via HTTPS.  With the following script, memory usage increases constantly:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET=>'https://www.google.com/');
while (1) {
  $response = $ua->request($request);
  sleep(1);
}
```

This other script has no problems:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET=>'http://www.google.com/'); # https => http
while (1) {
  $response = $ua->request($request);
  sleep(1);
}
```

Perl 5.12.3 / LWP 5.837 / Crypt::SSLeay 0.58 / Mac OS X 10.7.4

Does anyone know a way around this?

---

**UPDATE**

Perl 5.12.4 / LWP 6.05 / Crypt::SSLeay 0.64 / Mac OS X 10.8.4

The memory leak still exists when connecting through HTTPS.  To try it out, run the sample script on the terminal, and see the memory grow and grow with the Activity Monitor.

---

**UPDATE**

After some testing I found out that, with the recent upgrade of my libraries, there is still a memory leak, but **it only happens when you call certain addresses** over HTTPS.  In the above example I was calling https://www.google.com, and it happens to be one of those addresses.  For instance, this code gives me no memory leaks:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET=>'https://twitter.com/'); # www.google.com => twitter.com
while (1) {
  $response = $ua->request($request);
  sleep(1);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I reported the bug and some other people have confirmed my findings:  https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=88287

Comment: Version or Perl/LWP/Crypt::SSLeay? Platform?

Comment: Are you expecting the size of your program to shrink? On Unix, they don't do that. The high water mark just rises, and as memory is freed, it is kept in the pool for the program to reuse, but they never shrink themselves.

Comment: I just added the version numbers.  No, I'm not expecting it to shrink, but this script is some kind of a bot, and after just a couple of days running, the script was already using 500 Mb.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, It should plateau, and it should do so rather quickly.

Comment: If the leak is in C code, `valgrind` should find it.

Comment: @ikegami yes and no, not if the retrieved pages keep getting bigger.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, He's always retrieving the same page. You're not helping.

Comment: @ikegami - My goodness! Why? ;-)

Comment: @Len Jaffe, the code above is not the actual bot, it is just a simple test for tracking the memory leak.

Comment: Are you or fetching different pages, or the same page each time?

Comment: What happens if you create a new request object each time?  This isn't a leak if for some reason it is just making your request object larger each pass through the loop.

Comment: @ysth, I don't think that's what's happening here.  The request object is created outside of the loop, so only one object is being created.  Plus, the memory doesn't grow if the requested URL is an http one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, with perl 5.10, Crypt 0.58, Lwp 6.02 the memory usage is constant. try to upgrade your perl modules to the latest one.

If the issue is still present, create an RT ticket for this issue and the maintaner of this module will fix the leak.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you.  I will check that up and update the question for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, at least for me, that you can work around this problem by disabling verify hostname:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 });
```

Obviously this is not recommended if security is important to your application!